# Which URL does CreateView in Django redirects to when the success_url is not provided?

Tags: django

I am learning Class-based views in Django(inheriting from generic views) and stumbled upon a code for CreateView which did not provide any success_url. But after creation, I am getting redirected to DetailView (i.e, the page describing a particular object, in this case the object just created). I am not sure how this redirection is happening. Can anyone help me with this?

```
# ...other imports...
# ...
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

#... other views...

class TweetCreateView(FormUserNeededMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = TweetModelForm
    template_name = "tweets/create_view.html"

class TweetDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Tweet

#...other views...
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the model used in the `CreateView` has a `get_absolute_url` method, it will be used to determine the success url

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Iain Shelvington : "If the model used in the CreateView has a get_absolute_url method, it will be used to determine the success url"

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms